# Spring beans scope: singleton vs prototype

Tags: spring, java

Читаю документацию [по релизу 4.0.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-prototype), в частности про инициализацию и видимость бинов:

```
The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific bean is made. That is, the bean is injected into another bean or you request it through a getBean() method call on the container. As a rule, use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the singleton scope for stateless beans.
```

Смущает последнее предложение: почему именно так? Почему для stateless-бинов нужно держать один инстанс на контейнер (singleton scope), тогда как statefull-бины каждый раз инициализируются (prototype scope)? Разве не наоборот?

Stateless ведь нужны для для задачи запрос-ответ (они immutable и thread-safe по умолчанию). По аналогии в ejb-контейнерах обычно создается пул из некоторого количества инстансов одного бина, которые возвращаются клиенту по мере надобности, тогда как statefull живут подольше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stateless - еще не означает immutable и/или thread-safe. Все, что на самом деле означает stateless - это невозможность хранения состояния между запросами. Stateful - соответственно означает наличие возможности хранения состояния между запросами.

Допустим у вас есть сервис уровня доступа к данным, который просто выполняет операции над БД и возвращает вам данные. Сам сервис - stateless, т.к. не обладает состоянием, связанным с запросом. Достаточно иметь ровно один такой бин на приложение и его scope будет singleton. При этом он может например кэшировать какие-то данные и это будет внутренним состоянием самого сервиса, что сделает его одновременно mutable и небезопасным, с т.з. многопоточной среды.

Хорошим примером stateful бина может быть пользовательская сессия, т.к. она сохраняет состояние между запросами (но в Spring для этого есть свой scope). Соответственно у нас может быть stateless бин SessionManager, который является синглтоном и фабрикой statefull бинов типа Session, которые имет scope prototype.

В EJB, кстати, stateless бин определен как бин, который может иметь собственное состояние, вследствие чего к нему запрещен многопоточный доступ, из-за чего контейнеру требуется пул таких объектов.

Comment: Судя по всему, я пытаюсь натянуть концепцию EJB-бинов на спринговые бины... В EJB stateless запрещают многопоточность и работают через пул (и не хранят результат между вызовами), а синглтоны существуют в единственном экземпляре на контейнер, и многопоточность регулирутеся через аннотации @Lock к методам (если дефолтная не устраивает). В вашем примере про SessionManager в роли фабрики понятно, а как же тогда statefull бины будут хранить состояние между запросами, когда prototype scope подразумевает "creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific bean is made"?

Comment: @Vladimir Kishlaly А кто вам мешает не делать запрос к фабрике сессий, если сессия у вас уже есть?

Comment: значит, statefull нельзя autowire-ить, а получать только фабрикой?

Comment: @Vladimir Kishlaly ну откуда такие вызовы? Даже из цитаты из документации следует, что как минимум один раз такой бин заавтовайрится в синглтон-бин.