# Нет понимания, какой scope использовать при конфигурировании бинов

Tags: spring, тестирование, configuration, dependency-injection, scope

Здравствуйте.

Помогите, пожалуйста, у меня нет понимания, когда и какой scope использовать. 
Допустим, есть просто jms конфиг для клиента. 
В бин клиента инжектится `clientJmsTemplate`. Главный вопрос, не сделал ли я здесь неявной ошибки?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JmsClientConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype") //Environment env необходим для того, чтобы url можно было подставить в рантайме (через аргументы main())
  public ConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory(Environment env) throws Exception {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    String url = env.getProperty(..., String.class);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(url);
    return new SingleConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
  }

  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public JmsTemplate clientJmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) throws Exception {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(clientConnectionFactory);
    return jmsTemplate;
  }
  ...
}
```

1. Вроде все хорошо, я могу обявить клиента как `@Component` с `@Scope("prototype")` и насоздавать себе много клиентов как мне и хотелось. Никаких подводных камней тут не лежит в таком случае?
2. Возможно стоило для `jmsTemplate` установить `@Scope("prototype")`, а  для `ConnectionFactory` `@Scope("singleton")` ?
3. Тестирование. Допустим, мне надо подменить подключение.

   3.1 Я могу для тестов наследоваться от `JmsClientConfiguration` и "подменить" метод `clientConnectionFactory(Environment env)`, на свой, а потом заинжектить клиента в тест, верно?

   3.2 Могу лишь изменить проперти у `Enviroment env` если этого мне будет достаточно, верно?

   3.3 А без наследования как-то можно сделать подмену? Да и как это лучше сделать?

   3.4 Как в тестах подменить `ConnectionFactory` для нескольких клиентов, чтобы у них у всех был разное подключение? Сейчас ведь `Environment env` имеет одно значение и все клиенты будут использовать один `url`.

Comment: Пока ясно одно, если `clientConnectionFactory` является prototype, тогда она не будет закрыта во время закрытия контекста. Могут остаться треды, которые используют её и после выхода из `main()`

Comment: Ответы на вопросы с правильным выбором scope перечислены здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/319753